# In handwritten digit recognition problem using logistic regression, what changes needed to add another class "Not a Digit"

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, multiclass-classification, image-recognition, multilabel-classification

In handwritten digit recognition problem using logistic regression, normal implementation would forcibly classify even a picture of dog or cat as a digit. To eliminate this, what changes are needed to add another class i.e. "Not a Digit" to already existing 10 classes (0 to 9) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using one vs all classification, you can use a condition where if no class reach a minimum of probability, then it is not a number.
Or you can train the classifier with another class "Not a Digit".
Or maybe use a pipeline of two classifiers, one that tells you if a picture is a number or not, and if it is a number, classify that number.

Answer (score 0):

[Logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) is normally used to perform binary classification, which answers a **yes or no** question, e.g.:

1. Is this an 8 or not?
2. Will it rain today or not?

Perhaps I have misunderstood your explanation, but it sounds like you are trying to perform *multi-class classification*, i.e. to classify an image as one of a certain number of options. So a single image must contain (be classified as) a number from the list: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

Usually, to add an extra class to a model that already does this, you would need to adjust the final output of the model to predict [a one-hot vector](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f) that is simply one element longer!

In the specific case of the Scikit-Learn [**LogosticRegression**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) class, it seems as though you don't need to specify anything - the class will automatically use a multinomial model and relevant optimiser as soon as it sees that data is not binary (i.e. a yes-no model as explained above).

Have a look at [this official tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_sparse_logistic_regression_20newsgroups.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-sparse-logistic-regression-20newsgroups-py), which should a multinomial model trained on a dataset with a target variable that has a total of 20 classes. The number of features (`n_classes` is equal to `20`) is not passed to the model at all, it is inferred.